# How to avoid wrong picture of sender when forwarding a meeting in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Just a minor annoyance: when an initial invitee delegates(let's say Jack) to another person (let's say Jim) using the "Forward", the e-mail generated by outlook has sender "{Invitee} on behalf of {Chairman}" and the picture shown is the Chairman's picture (lets say John). This is wrong because the email is sent by the initial invitee (Jack). It should be picture of the of Jack, instead of chairman John.

This is confusing to the receiver (Jim), who sees the picture of the Chairman (John) but the text written is by the initial invitee (Jack).

Question: any workaround to avoid the wrong photo showing up?

Question asked on behalf of a colleague.

Comment: If you're sending "On behalf of" , then you're posing as the user you're sending on behalf of, and so the picture is of that user, not you.

Comment: Thanks @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - once meeting is forwarded by Jack, Jim received an invitation from Jack, written ''Jack on behalf of John''. In that sense, it would be more appropriate to have Jack's picture instead of John. More over, it is Jack, who forwarded the invitation saying, please go on behalf of me, as I will be busy with something else.


![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kfXFe.jpg